# How do you fix this gradle/intellij issue where it cannot find the plugin for kotlin multiplatform?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I have tried using multiple different JVM's for kotlin and gradle see if that would work. This repository is cloned and I haven't made any major changes to it. I want to be able to deploy this open source version and modify it so that I can test out my reinforcement learning model.

Please let me know if anyone has any insight into how to address this

Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform', version: '1.5.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform:org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform.gradle.plugin:1.5.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  maven(https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap)
  maven2(https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/)
  MavenRepo
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:222)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$resolvePluginRequests$4(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:148)
  at org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:207)
  at org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:201)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolvePluginRequests(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:146)
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:86)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.PluginRequestsHandler.handle(PluginRequestsHandler.kt:48)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.applyPluginsTo(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:192)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.applyPluginsTo(Interpreter.kt:373)
  at Program.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.eval(Interpreter.kt:506)